# How do I implement a transparent high availability database fail-over solution?

Tags: database, high-availability

How do I implement a transparent high availability database fail-over solution for my website?

Comment: This is entirely database dependent - each vendor does it differently, if at all. Specify a database if you want a useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

The global answer to cover each and every single possible scenario is:

**Clustering**

That's about as specific of an answer as you can get without providing at *least* your operating system and choice of DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize Amazon's Cloudfront, Load Balancing, and Auto Scaling features with their RDS product.